# Java's List Interface

Tags: java

This is a very simple question.

I have seen explanations on `List` and it says it is an Interface. I also understand how the List (arraylist) is used.

But my question, if `List` is an Interface, then why do not we use the keyword `implements` to use `List`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you would like to provide your own implementation for `List`, yes you can `implement`.

[ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is one of the implementation for `List` and yes it does `implement` the `List` interface.

Answer (score 5):

Because you only use `implements` when writing your own implementation of an interface, and I assume you're not doing that for `java.util.List`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand the concept of interface in Java. There are many classes which implements the `List` interface and you can use whichever suits your need. `Arraylist` is one such example.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the source code for ArrayList, you will definitely find the following at the top of the file:

`class ArrayList implements List`